# Loki installation - 3rd party drivers and UEFI secure boot

Tags: system-installation, release-loki, uefi, thirdpartyapps

During the installation routine of Loki there's a prompt to choose whether to install 3rd-party-drivers. If you choose yes, the prompt tells you you have to disable UEFI secure boot because otherwise the 3r-party-drivers cannot be installed. Also, you have to choose a passphrase needed to disable UEFI secure boot.

I'm wondering if the disabling is permanent or just a one-time thing for the purpose of installation. Also, the password I chose was never asked for during the installation procedure. Any ideas?

Comment: I have this issue.. (whit universal-usb-installer), then I used ruffus and works ...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't reproduced your situation specificaly but I have been trough same condition once on pure Ubuntu. The package that does that on Ubuntu is "mokutil". If no prompt was shown to you to disable secure boot chances are you already are on "unsecure" mode. It showed to me very early on boot. Probably shown by the BIOS itself. Disabling it is permanent and should pose no real threat. All it does it to allow non signed code to be loaded on boot. If you ever decide to go back to your stock OS you could re-enable it on BIOS after a factory reset.

[More information on Secure Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Secure_boot_2).

Answer (score -1):

I created the USB with rufus and works well. Even with 3rd-party-drivers checked